# Why am I getting "Permission Denied" when trying to write to NFS mount using AWS EC2 EFS mount as server and OSX as client

Tags: amazon-web-services, nfs

I have a folder like this

```bash
$ ls -al /mnt/efs/main/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root   6144 May 24 02:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root     18 May 23 23:59 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody 6144 May 24 03:04 html
```

I have an nfs server that has an exports like...

```
/mnt/efs/main/html .../24(rw,no_root_squash)
```

but I get

```
exportfs: /mnt/efs/main/html requires fsid= for NFS export
```

so I add

```
/mnt/efs/main/html .../24(rw,no_root_squash,fsid=1)
```

then run

```
sudo exportfs -av
```

and get

```
exporting .../24:/mnt/efs/main/html
```

but when I try to mount **on the client** everything works and the permissions look open...

```bash
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport ...:/mnt/efs/main/html ~/aws-dir
> ls -al aws-dir                                                          
total 8
drwxrwxrwx    2 65534          65534  6144 May 23 23:04 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 198 ....    staff  6336 May 23 23:10 ..
```

but when I try a touch

```bash
~/aws-dir  > touch test
touch: test: Operation not supported
```

How do I set it up to allow me to write from the client?

Turns out the problem seems to be related to the fact that the file is on an efs mount. Even stranger the file gets created but I can't see it on the drive unless I am on the EC2 machine.

I changed to a normal EBS mount and it worked fine.

Comment: Two questions :a) why fsid 1? Set it to 0, b) areu you are accessing as user root or regular user?

Comment: If I use 0 it won't even let me mount the drive.